# how to run django server on background at startup?

Tags: python, django, server

I wanna Django runserver on the background when I start my laptop I'm using ubuntu.
I tried using "screen" but this is not what am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For background runserver on OS startup, you can pick Gunicorn or Supervisord, or Uwsgi as process runner. These folks can run your project in auto mode, and if you make them as ubuntu services, they can boot up and run project after OS startup.

[gunicorn](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04)

[uwsgi](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04#setting-up-the-uwsgi-application-server)

[supervisord](https://rahmonov.me/posts/run-a-django-app-with-nginx-gunicorn-and-supervisor/)

Last link combines gunicorn with supervisord: Gunicorn will run project by command, and supervisord will be a process watcher for gunicorn.

Almost all links have receipt for configuring nginx, you may skip this step, because it's used for servers to proxy requests to your app's process. On laptop you may run project on localhost, it's just fine for debug or development.